# google distance matrix API 3

Tags: matrix, distance

I have code to calculate distance place to another place using google distance matrix API, but for free its limited just 100 elements per query. So I make code for solve the problem using looping code such as for elements , My code is PHP, javascript , and I parse latitude and longitude data from MySql. Anyone know some error of my code below ? because It don't appear anything if I click calculate button. Actualy I have modifie the code from this URL https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix , And this is my Code :

```
function hitung (){
  service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    for (m = 0 ; m < l-80 ; m++ ){
        asal = originarray[m];
        for (n = 0 ; n < l-80 ; n++ ){
            tujuan = destarray [n];
            calculateDistances();
        }
    }
  }
  function calculateDistances() {

 //var s = 0;

  //for (m = 0 ; m < l-80 ; m++ ){
    //  asal = originarray[m];
    //for (n = 0 ; n < l-80 ; n++ ){
        //servicearray[s] = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        //tujuan = destarray [n];       
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
       //origins: [origin1, origin2],
      // destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
       origins: asal,
     destinations: tujuan,
        //origins: originarray,
        //destinations: destarray,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, callback);
     // s++;

    //}

// }        
  }

  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
      //outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
     // deleteOverlays();

      for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
       // addMarker(origins[i], false);
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        //  addMarker(destinations[j], true);
          outputDiv.innerHTML += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
              + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
              + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
    var icon;
    if (isDestination) {
      icon = destinationIcon;
    } else {
      icon = originIcon;
    }
    geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: peta,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          icon: icon
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
          + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function deleteOverlays() {
    if (markersArray) {
      for (i in markersArray) {
        markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      }
      markersArray.length = 0;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I think that the problem is in your arrays (tujuan and asal). I search to solve this but I don't find answer about that. If you find the answer, can you send it here? I do the same if I found.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're receiving a response from Google by logging the response...

```
function callback(response, status) {
    console.log(response);
}
```